# Angular 8, IE11, ngx-image-cropper bugged, ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11, crop

I'm using Angular 8, ngx-image-cropper: "^2.0.2". I have a problem in ie11 with cropper. It is working perfectly in chrome but in ie11 when I upload an image it starts bugging [component with cropper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDp25.png) and drops error [error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksxs2.png). The same error happens when I try to move/resize cropper, app freezes for 1 sec too.
I've had error Object doesn't support property or method 'toBlob' and added polyfill that is suggested for ngx-image-cropper: "^2.0.2" to work in ie11 (https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/blob/master/canvas-toBlob.js), and it fixed the blob error.

I've noticed that when I resize that I do not receive cropped image back.
Here is code from my image cropper component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ResponsiveComponent } from '../../../core/component/responsive.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-cropper-dialog',
  templateUrl: './image-cropper-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-cropper-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class ImageCropperDialogComponent extends ResponsiveComponent implements OnInit {

  /**
   * Cropped image
   */
  croppedImage: File;

  /**
   * Sting representation of a cropped image
   */
  base64: string;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ImageCropperDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
  }

  /**
   * Close dialog
   */
  closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  /**
   * On image save
   */
  onCrop(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close({
      file: this.croppedImage,
      base64: this.base64
    });
  }

  /**
   * On image loaded
   */
  imageLoaded(): void {}

  /**
   * On image cropped
   */
  imageCropped(event): void {
    this.croppedImage = new File([event.file], this.data.image.name);
    this.base64 = event.base64;
  }
}
// html code
<div class="c-dialog__content cover" mat-dialog-content>
        <image-cropper [imageFile]="data.image"
                       [maintainAspectRatio]="data.aspectRatio ? true : false"
                       [aspectRatio]="data.aspectRatio ? data.aspectRatio : 1"
                       [outputType]="'both'"
                       [resizeToWidth]="data.resizeTo ? data.resizeTo : 1200"
                       (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
                       (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
                       style="transition: opacity 300ms ease">
        </image-cropper>

        <p class="color-silver-chalice with-padding">
            Move and resize the selection until you are happy with the preview and then click Save.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="c-dialog__actions o-flex-justify-end" mat-dialog-actions>
        <button *ngIf="from1024"
                (click)="onCrop()"
                mat-flat-button
                class="c-dialog__save"
                color="primary"
                [disabled]="!croppedImage">
            Crop
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please check in the console whether you are getting any other error or warning in the console or not. If yes, please try to provide information about it. Check whether you are getting the security error. If yes, then this can be a [similar issue](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/issues/21)

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for the reply, but I'm not getting any other error. That's why it's so frustrating.

Comment: It will be also hard for us to make any guess about the cause of the issue without any error message. I suggest you create a new issue on their GitHub [issues](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/issues) page.